# ES5 shim for binding functions is Javascript

Tags: binding, shim

Below is a ES5 shim for JS binding.I dont understand  **self**.apply in the bound function.
I know how to use apply method, but where is **self** pointing to in this case ? It it supposed to be a
function, but here **self** looks like an object.

```
if ( !Function.prototype.bind ) {

       Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {

        var slice = [].slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments, 1),
        self = this,

        nop = function () {},

        bound = function () {
        return self.apply( this instanceof nop ? this : ( obj || {} ), // self in this line is supposed  
        to // represent a function ?
        args.concat( slice.call(arguments) ) );
        };

        nop.prototype = self.prototype;
        bound.prototype = new nop();
        return bound;
        };
  }
```

Comment: I know this is an ancient question at this point in time, but it comes up pretty high in Google search analytics.  The accepted answer is pretty misleading. I've posted a new answer with some additional detail. Take a look if you are interested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have in mind that in javascript *almost* everything is an object.

So you have it right there:

> self = this

So, self is not *representing* anything, self *is* the instance.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is being used in the shim you have listed to accommodate the fact that `this` changes along with scope changes.  Within the direct scope of the Function.prototype.bind function `this` will refer to the object on which the bind function was called.

Once you enter the scope of the nested `bound` function `this` has changed; so the author has assigned `self = this` within the `bind` function to allow the value of `this` at the time `bind` is called to remain available to the `bound` function via lexical scoping (closure).

Scoping within JavaScript can get pretty complicated; for a detailed explanation take a look at this article.

[Everything you wanted to know about JavaScript scope.](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

Comment: Hi bigtunacan. 
In the meanwhile I learned a lot about JS including its's functional nature, object-oriented style and ofcourse js scope and closure. From this example I can remember that I didn't understand that prototype object will be inherited by the function which is - object.
But anyway thanks for your answer.